# How to reassign lead to a queue in apex trigger

Tags: apex

I have a list of leads in a map that I want to reassign a queue dynamically in code. How can I do this? Below is my code snippet that shows how the Map is being filled with leads that belong to a specific owner.

```
    Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id, Integer> getNumberOfLeadsForEachOwner = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    for (Lead leadObj : trigger.new){
            ownerIds.add(leadObj.OwnerId);
    }
    
    
        AggregateResult[] currentLeadsByOwner = [SELECT COUNT(Id)leadsCount, OwnerId
                                                 FROM Lead
                                                 WHERE OwnerId IN :ownerIds AND Status = 'Open - Not Contacted'
                                                 GROUP BY OwnerId];
    
    
        for (AggregateResult aggResult : currentLeadsByOwner){
            getNumberOfLeadsForEachOwner.put((Id)aggResult.get('OwnerId'), (Integer)aggResult.get('leadsCount'));
        }
    
    if (trigger.isInsert){
        for (Lead leadInstance : trigger.new){
    
                if (getNumberOfLeadsForEachOwner.containsKey(leadInstance.OwnerId)){
                    if (String.valueOf(leadInstance.OwnerId).substring(0, 3) == '005'){
                        //Check if the number of leads per owner is greater than 3 and they may not create a lead for themselves
                        if ((Integer)getNumberOfLeadsForEachOwner.get(leadInstance.OwnerId) >= getMaximumNumberOfOpenLeads.Open_Leads_Max__c){
                            leadInstance.addError('You have exceeded the number of open leads that you can have at a time.');
                        }
                        else if(LeadTriggerHandler.opportunityInstance != null && LeadTriggerHandler.opportunityInstance == true){
                            
                            
                            if(some condition){
                           //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO REASSIGN THE LEAD FROM THE OWNER TO A QUEUE NAMED 'New Lead'
                           }

                            System.debug('Owner is changed insert');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I now want to reassign a lead upon meeting a certain condition to a queue called 'New Leads'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign a record to a queue, you need to query the queue:

```
Group newLeadQueue = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Type = 'Queue' and Name = 'New Leads'];
```

...

```
leadRecord.OwnerId = newLeadQueue.Id;
```

Comment: I am getting a `List has no rows for assignment to SObject Trigger.LeadTrigger: line 20, column 1` error

This is what I have at line 20:   

  `Group newLeadQueue = [SELECT Id  FROM Group WHERE TYPE = 'Queue' AND Name = 'New Leads'  LIMIT 1];`. The error suggests that I don't have rows in the Group sObject. Must I add test records in the Group object in Salesforce?

Comment: @Harold_Finch Maybe you have the wrong name? For your unit test, though, you would need to insert a new Group object and assign a QueueSObject record to allow cases.

Comment: This is for leads and not cases. Let me try write a unit test

Comment: @Harold_Finch I meant to say Leads, honest. That's the lack of coffee talking. Still, the same thing applies. Create a Group with a QueueSObject tied to it, and then you should be able to get your unit test to pass.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Salesforce after 6 years of .Net development. Do you mind showing me sample code of how to create this QueueSObject ?

Comment: Like so? `QueueSObject queueSObj = new QueueSObject(SobjectType = 'Lead', QueueId = g.Id);
 insert queueSObj;`

Comment: @Harold_Finch Yes, like that.